# MySQL query is very slow (15 minutes)

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, optimization

I was previously using SQLite for a personal project and due to a constraint of having it available online, I decided to make the switch to MySQL. I converted my database to the MySQL equivalent but I just noticed that performance is VERY poor. This is a 70 mb database with around 600k records total. The query I am running is an INNER JOIN that executes in less than 500 ms using SQLite but the same query using MySQL takes 15 minutes.

```sql
SELECT has.tag_id, has.image_id
FROM has
INNER JOIN image ON image.image_id = has.image_id
INNER JOIN person ON person.person_id = image.person_id
WHERE person.name="Random Person"
```

- `has` table has 80k records
- `image` table has 290k records
- `person` table has 500 records

Here is the structure of the three tables:

```sql
create table media.person
(
    person_id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    name         text not null
)
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create table media.image
(
    id           int auto_increment,
    image_id     int  not null,
    person_id int  not null,
    link         text not null,
    checksum     text null,
    constraint id
        unique (id)
)
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

alter table media.image
    add primary key (id);

create table media.has
(
    id       int auto_increment
        primary key,
    tag_id   int not null,
    image_id int not null
)
    collate = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Note that I added a primary key to the `has` table because I suspected it might have been the source of the problem, but it isn't and SQLite was doing fine without that primary key.

The database uses the InnoDB engine. Here is the output of the `mysql --version` command:

```
mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.30
```

Where could the problem come from? I can understand a small loss of performance because MySQL is heavier than SQLite but certainly not to the point of going from 500 ms to 15 minutes for such a simple query.

EDIT:

I just ran the query again, this time it took 7 minutes. I used slow_query_logs but it doesn't tell me much.

```
# Time: 2020-07-13T07:18:22.526915Z
# User@Host: media[media] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:   205
# Query_time: 429.434270  Lock_time: 0.000751 Rows_sent: 501  Rows_examined: 223451
use media;
SET timestamp=1594624702;
/* ApplicationName=DataGrip 2020.1.3 */ SELECT has.tag_id, has.image_id
                                FROM has
                                INNER JOIN image ON image.image_id = has.image_id
                                INNER JOIN person ON person.person_id = image.person_id
                                WHERE person.name="Random Person";
```

Comment: @Lennart thank you, that was indeed the problem. Adding a primary key image_id, tag_id reduced the query time from 15 minutes to 600 ms.

Comment: checkout explain. It will help you realize how the DBMS evaluates your questions.

Comment: I just tried it and unfortunately the most useful part for me - EXPLAIN ANALYZE - isn't available as I'm using MySQL 5.7. The query still takes around 600 ms compared to the 280-300 ms it takes using SQLite but EXPLAIN shows me that it's already using indexes and primary keys so I suppose it can't do much more.

Comment: You should also add an index on Image (image_id, person_id)

Comment: I already have two separate indexes for image_id and person_id so unfortunately it still takes 600 ms.

Comment: A composite index is way way better than two indidividual indexes.

Comment: Well I figured that since composite indexes are ordered and I want to be able to search for an image id, a person id or both at the same time, it would be better to have individual indexes. Otherwise I would have to create one index (image_id, person_id) and another (person_id, image_id), wouldn't I? Or should I use three indexes in this case (two separates and one composite)?

Comment: In that case, I would use two indexes (image_id, person_id) and (person_id) or the other way around. You may even have two composite indexes (image_id, person_id), (person_id, image_id). I guess image_id, person_id is unique so I would get rid of the id and use person_id, image_id as primary key.

Comment: I ended up doing the first version with a composite index and an individual one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add indexes:

1. image (person_id, image_id)
2. has (image_id, tag_id) - you can remove id column from this table and make this index a primary key
3. It is not the best idea to use "text" data type for person.name column. It would be better to use varchar or nvarchar. For example, varchar(100) should be enough. Then create index on this column too: person (name).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I added a primary key between image_id and tag_id and it already improved by a lot but I'll make sure to add indexes too.